# How to set specific class properties for a PHPunit test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

What is a good best practice for phpunit to set some default configuration values in a test?

I'm thinking of values like

username

client id no.

so on..

Normally I would set this using the constructor or some setters but I'm not sure how to do this when I only have a class like this

```
class RestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
```

For example I'm trying to make test cases for a REST and SOAP service.

I need to specify the url/user and pass but they change on dev/test/production so I need a clean way to specify them.

Comment: As neither answer satisfied your requirements, can you go into more depth about precisely what you need? A concrete example might help.

Answer (score 5):

If you have some default values like a UserId that you need in every testcase of your test I'd suggest setting those in the `setUp` method of your class.

Just an example for setting the values:

```
class MtTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    // As a property
    private $testUser = 7;

    // In the setUp
    public function setUp() {
        $this->testUser = 7;
        $this->defaultName = "BOB";
        $this->MtClass = new Mt();
    }

    public function testFoo() {
         $this->assertTrue($this->MtClass->userExists($this->testUser));
    }
}
```

If you have a set of values that you need to feed into one test method use DataProviders like @SilverLight (+1) suggested.

### Response to comment:

If you need some kind of environment setup (for whatever you are trying to do, I'll just go with username for now since i can't guess) you could set those in your [`PHPUnit Bootstrap`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.phpunit) (or the file you pass to --bootstrap):

bootstrap.php

```
<?php
define("PHPUnit_Username", "Fuuu");
// or
$phpunitConfig = new Array(
     "username" => "fuu",
)
// or whatever suits you there. No reason for me to type a config object i guess
class MyPHPUnitConfig {
     public function getUsername() { return "wtf"; }
}
```

and maybe have your own base Testclass

```
<?php
class MyBaseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->config = new MyPHPUnitConfig();
    }
}
```

and extend from that. Or use `setUpBeforeClass` to only do it once per test class.

---

If that doesn't answer your question i just don't get what you are ameing at. It's a testcase, it doesn't have any strong dependencies and it [`kinda shouldn't have any (Isolation)`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/goals.html) and i don't guess your problem is how to get a value into your setUp function is it? (Because thats kinda not a phpunit issue).

Let me know if that helped

Comment: This is hardcoded, I need a flexible configuration. Would you do this kind of code In a normal class?

Comment: No, because it's a Unit test. Known values in, expected values out. I didn't expect that you need some kind of environment settings but just pull them in your setUp class or in the PHPUnit bootstrap. I'll edit a little

Comment: I think this is the right way. I added a little example to be clear.

Comment: If you have an extra set of credential **only** for testing I'd create a baseTestClass like "MySoapBaseTest" and put them there. That also allows you to mock the service if you need to. It's not a config file but it's a nice place to maintain them i guess. If every dev needs this own I'd say: Put them in the (dev)application config of your project and pull them out from there in the BaseClass :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [data providers](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers.examples.DataTest.php):

```
<?php
class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        return array(
          array(0, 0, 0),
          array(0, 1, 1),
          array(1, 0, 1),
          array(1, 1, 3)
        );
    }
}
?>
```

data provider can contain any type of information, including usersname, client id  etc.

Comment: I need a generic configuration that works for any function not a provider.